# BrowserSync : Strange thing in the folder tree

Tags: sass, gulp, browser-sync

I'm settings new tools for frontend dev, among us, BrowserSync to reload pages after sass compiling via Gulpfile.
After modifying scss files, I found that modifications aren't applied, and looking for why, I see that the BrowserSync folder tree under the proxy's port 3000 isn't the same as real on Lamp (via FTP), so scss files disapears after compiling them..
Example of scss file path :

```
http://xxx:3000/sites/all/themes/CyranoD6_susy2_mg/css/css/layout/_layout-diapo-frontpage.scss
```

instead of

```
http://xxx:3000/sites/all/themes/CyranoD6_susy2_mg/scss/layout/_layout-diapo-frontpage.scss
```

Do I need to set something in my gulpfile ? I think about a misconfiguration in gulpfile, in the map.css destination folder, seem BS put/look for files at this same place.
This is my browserSync task:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
     // Watch files
//    var files = [
//        './js/*.js',
//        '**/*.php',
//        './**/*.tpl.php',
//        './images/**/*.{png,jpg,gif,svg}'
//    ];
       browserSync.init({
        //changer l'adresse du site pour lequel utiliser browserSync
        proxy: "http://vmdom.vmdev",
        open: false,
        logLevel: 'debug',
        logConnections: true
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with browserSync. Let me see your sass gulp task because maybe it is happening something there.

Comment: details are an another question, because after searching about this issue, I think it come from gulp-sass or gulp-sourcemaps. You can replay me on the another thread.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045467/gulp-sass-scss-file-not-compiled-variables

Comment: I was right then :)